# Wordpress Insert Data from Form not Working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, insert

I'm developping a wordpress plugin which gets data from `$_POST` method and inserts these data into my database.

the plugin code is something like this :

```
    if(isset($_POST["name"])) $my_name = $_POST["name"];
    else $my_name = "";
    register($my_name);


function my_function( $my_name )
{

global $wpdb;
echo $my_name ;
$wpdb->get_results("insert into table_name values('".$my_name."');");
echo $my_name ;
}
```

this code prints the `$my_name` content one time only and the insert query doesn't work.

note that when i replace the query with this query the row is inserted in the database :

```
insert into table_name values('some text');
```

any help, please

Comment: You don't need the semicolon in the statement - ".$my_name."');")

Comment: Check this link : https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: no answer i've already checked this link and now answer . i think that wordpress doesn't allow the insertion of variables wich are passed by $_post method

Comment: use `$wpdb->query()` instead of `get_results`. Also check if query fulfills all requirements for insertion of row in that table